# Sending email from domain't address

Tags: java, api, email, java-8, jakarta-mail

How can i send a letter from domain's address? I just can't get it. It shows

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning 

 javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
 DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.yandex.ru", port 995, isSSL false
```

It can't connect to the host, but port is right.
What the properties should be to send an email from the domain?
Mine is:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//Enable tls session
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");//Enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.yandex.ru");//Server's host
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "995");//Server's port
```

I have [something]@domain.ru

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//Enable tls session
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");//Enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.yandex.ru");//Server's host
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "995");//Server's port

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("name@domain.ru", "password102030");
                    }
                });
        session.setDebug(true);


    try {

        Scanner to = new Scanner(toWho);
        while (to.hasNextLine())
        {
            String touser = to.nextLine();

        try {
             if (howMany <= batch)
        {
            howMany++;
            System.out.println("Задержка "+delayevery/1000+" секунд");
            Thread.sleep(delayevery);
        }
        else
        {
            howMany = 0;
            System.out.println("Задержка "+delaybatch/1000+" секунд");
            Thread.sleep(delaybatch);
        }
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username,alias));

            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(touser));
            message.setSubject(subject);


             // Create the message part
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     BodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();

     if (image != "")
     imagePart.setContent("<img src=\""+image+"\">","text/html");
     // Now set the actual message
     messageBodyPart.setText(MailSender.message);

     // Create a multipar message
     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
     //Set image message part
     multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
     // Set text message part
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Part two is attachment
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

     if (attaching != "")      
      {
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attaching);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

     messageBodyPart.setFileName(javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.encodeWord(source.getName(),
            "UTF-8", null));
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
      }
     // Send the complete message parts
     message.setContent(multipart);


            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done "+(++counter));

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.print("База была не найдена.");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.print("Что-то неверно.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Port 995 is the POP3 over SSL port.  You might want port 465, which is the SMTP over SSL port.  Or more likely, since you've set the starttls property, you just want port 25, or possibly port 587.  Those are plain text SMTP ports.  The starttls property will cause SSL/TLS to be enabled after connecting to the port.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You have got to enable ssl session:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```